# Any good EAI (Enterprise Application Integration) books?

Tags: eai

One of the jobs I'm looking at requires good experience with EAI.

Was wondering if anyone can recommend good EAI books / resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this book for several years, and I still regard it as a valuable reference.

[Enterprise Integration Patterns: Designing, Building, and Deploying Messaging Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683)

The author also has a [list of books](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/books1.html) on his website.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a classical eai book i like "Enterprise Service Bus" by Dave Chapell -> it adresses many Integration challenges and gives a rough understanding of some key principles of "modern integration"

The already mentioned Enterprise Integration Patterns is also very good for diving into some conceptual background.